# Adding a lookup entity without manually adding to related entities navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity called Requirements and an entity called Actions and an entity called Requirement_Fulfillment that is a composite of the Requirement and Action primary keys but also has an integer field.

To better illustrate, Requirement has a navigation property Requirement_Fulfillmments, Action also has a navigation property Requirement_Fulfillments, and Requirement_Fulfillment has 2 navigation properties for Requirement and Action.

If I want to add a Requirement_Fulfillment, and I specify the primary key so that it matches up with Requirement's and Action' primary key will it automatically be added to their navigation properties?

Or do I need to manually add it to the navigation properties of both sides or one side?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation properties are just that, a link to the other entity. You wouldn't add to the navigation property, you would add to the entity itself and then access it via a navigation property.